# Selecting an image on property change in viewmodel

Tags: c#, wpf

I would like to implement a visual indication (light bulb) in my WPF application, that glows for a short time whenever a property (`string RFID`, raises `PropertyChanged` event) in my viewmodel (MVVM) changes. `DataContext` of my window is set to the viewmodel. I got two images showing a light bulb on/off.

I tried with triggers and styles, but it didn't work out:

```
    <Image>
        <Image.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Image">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value="LightGrey.png"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="RFID" Value="???">
                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="LightGreen.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Image.Style>
    </Image>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have a boolean `IsLightOn` property in your ViewModel, and your whenever `RFID` fires a PropertyChanged event, the ViewModel turns `IsLightOn = true` and sets a timer which turns `IsLightOn = false` after X seconds

Comment: I have problems setting the trigger property to IsLightOn. I changed my sample code (see above) like this: '<Trigger Property="IsLightOn" Value="True">'. Error: Cannot find style property IsLightOn on the type Controls.Image.

Comment: @nabulke Change your `Trigger` to a `DataTrigger`. `<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsLightOn}" Value="True">`

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want the additional bool property as suggested. You can write a simple value converter that does this.

```
    class AnyToBoolConverter: IValueConverter   
    { 
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        { 
            return (value != null) ? true : false; 
        } 
          
        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) 
        { 
            return DependencyProperty.UnsetValue; 
        } 
    }
```

This converter will come in handy in many situations. And you can do this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=RFID, Converter={StaticResource boolConverter}}" Value="True"> 
      <Setter Property="Source" Value="LightGreen.png"/> 
</DataTrigger>
```